# How to improve the quality of my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-improvement

Yesterday I have asked this question regarding machine learning model exporting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368898/how-to-export-model-trained-in-r-and-load-in-python

Initially I asked a general question but because it got downvoted and two votes for close I decide to edit the question and add codes to it to make it more specific.

But after that also some one voted to close this question. I don't know where I made the mistake whether its my English or the quality of the question.

Now I am thinking to delete this question altogether but before that I want to find out what mistake I made in the question and how to improve it?

Comment: Pretty standard mistake, you described the task you need to complete.  You did not ask a question.  This happened because you did not research your task at all.  Trivially google "python load rdata file", the top 3 hits are SO questions that are an exact match.  Forth hit is a github project.  Show evidence of you actually having tried to use the existing solutions.  And in the unlikely case you are still stuck, now you have a *real* question to ask.  Stop treating SO like a personal code writing service and everybody is ahead.

Comment: 1-Your original question was of very very low quality. 2- The reasoning you've provided "*it is a scarce programme whereas Python is seen universally*" just sound like a potential XY problem (no actual problem to solve- rather "*but, I don't wanna!*" type of a problem). 3- As @HansPassant said, you haven't provided your attempts and it seem like it could be partially solved by Googling-hence it's just a dupe. 4- The recent CVs are probably a result of MOB voting. 5- You are basically looking for a tutorial as you haven't tried anything yourself, so this question is also probably off-topic too.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable input. I will try to avoid these mistakes in my future posts.

Comment: Of course, both the above comments should have been answers. Now you can't accept anything.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet That was a **prime** opportunity to advertise your [thread](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320364/answers-in-comments-revisited) regarding that topic! :o