# Answers in comments, revisited

Tags: discussion, comments

I've raised this topic [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247446/155739) more generally, with a terrible lack of success. But with this specific example I'm going to try this again as it's *really* starting to annoy me!

Observe:

[image: Example of answer-as-comment]

The entire answer to the question has been given as a comment. Why? Answerer didn't want rep? Couldn't be bothered to flesh it out to a couple more sentences? (Okay then just leave it to someone else entirely?) I've since answered the question properly, which basically just duplicated the comment's content. I don't like having to do that, but I was left with little choice.

The *entire purpose* of Stack Exchange is the Q&A model that differs from a forum-style stream of conversational posts. People who post answers as comments are apparently trying to take SE back to the model that it was invented to supplant. I hear "but I helped", as if "helping at all costs" was ever what this network was about. We have a Q&A model for a dang good reason!

Answers as comments cannot be downvoted, reviewed, edited or bountied. They do not contribute to the metric of "how many answers has this question?" which feeds into a few automated processes, various "can be marked as duplicate?" rules and so forth. These are all problems.

*Answers go in the answer section.*

Please, please, please, can we make this official somewhere? Or at least could somebody please agree with me?! :smileyface:

Comment: Well first that someone posts a *(potential)* answer in the comments could be: Too lazy to write a proper good answer, in a hurry, maybe not sure if it fully answers the question, ... and maybe other reasons as well. Now if you see this and as you said you just don't want to post the same, you could: write a comment and ask the user if he wants to post an answer, or just post it as community wiki.

Comment: I find most answers posted as comments are stab-in-the-dark answers, where the question does not have enough information to know for sure, but the answer is probable and enough to guess at. Is that possibly what happened here? From your screenshot, they were told it was correct only 4 minutes before, perhaps they were yet going to post an answer?

Comment: *The entire answer to the question has been given as a comment.* If that's possible, then the question is not that good in the first place, I'm afraid. Anyway, a possible reason for posting a comment is that the answer is common and simple enough that the commenter would end up posting it several times a day if they didn't use comments. E.g. how many "missing `$(document).ready()`" questions do you think we're willing to answer in a day?

Comment: Why bother with an answer if it's just going to be a dup?  So many questinos posters, repWhores etc. don't bother to look for dups, so why should I?  So, it it's short, may as well dump the dup answer to the dup question in the comments.   Why make any more effort than that on a bad question?

Comment: @Rizier123: _"maybe not sure if it fully answers the question,"_ Then why are they writing it down at all? _Be_ sure. Don't write something you don't even know yourself is true. Especially in a section where it cannot be downvoted/edited!

Comment: @Rizier123: _"you could: write a comment and ask the user if he wants to post an answer, or just post it as community wiki"_ Yeah, I _can_, but what a fuss! What a kefuffle! What a mess! Why can't we just do the Q&A thing properly from the start?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: _"Is that possibly what happened here?"_ No, it is not. The answerer is well-known, and the solution was clear. _"they were told it was correct"_ They already knew it was correct. It was a very easy question and I know the person who "answered" it.

Comment: Is the answer a duplicate, or typo problem then? Why bother posting a good answer when there already exist ones on the dupe?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: I don't know what you're referring to, sorry. What dupe? What typo? There are neither of those things at play here. Reasonable question, reasonable (if easy) solution... just the solution was first posted in the wrong place. I see that as a growing, systemic problem with this community. I'm asking to discuss that.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet (To your first response) There are a lot of people, which write something down in the comments, even if they are not sure at all. Now you say: *"Why can't we just do the Q&A thing properly from the start?"* When we want to do that, how would you define the rules for that? And what should we do if someone breaks these rules and posts an answer as a comment? Also if someone just knows half of the answer for sure and posts it as comment, should it be a comment or answer then? Where exactly would you draw the line in the rules between when to post a comment or an answer?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I was suggesting that there *might* be a duplicate, if "The answerer is well-known". I don't know if there is one or not.

Comment: @Rizier123: The comments section is for requesting clarification and for providing critique. Period. There's even a canned comment generated by the review system which states this explicitly. I don't know why everyone's suddenly treating comments on main as an answering/"hints & tips" venue. If you think you know half the answer (no, nobody knows anything "for sure" - that's why we have _votes_), go into a chatroom and discuss the question with other people in your tag. Then answer it fully. _In the answer section._

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: The answerer. Not the answer. :)

Comment: Fwiw, doesn't help to redact the name of the user posting the comment if you don't do the same in OP's response to it :)

Comment: @Barry: I realised the source material would be discoverable if anyone really wanted to (you could just search for the comment content, after all), but I just didn't see a reason to brazenly display their name on the post itself. I also commented to that person about the existence of this question. It's not my intention to demonise them whatsoever. This is a wider problem as I see more and more people doing this.

Comment: @Barry (lol) didn't see it as demonising. Just found it amusing that you took the effort to half-censor. Also, agree with your motivation here 100%

Comment: @Barry: Just want to be clear :)

Comment: Hey, guys, answers go in the Answers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: _"a possible reason for posting a comment is that the answer is common and simple enough that the commenter would end up posting it several times a day if they didn't use comments."_ I don't see how that's a valid reason. If you don't want to answer the question again, then don't. Or close it as a dupe if it's a dupe.

Comment: @Barry, yup, that's the SO Paradox -- we're here to help in the first place, but we don't want to answer dupes, and sometimes we don't have time to look for one, but we still want to help. So we post a short comment and go our merry ways. Keep in mind it's also simpler than having to fight for your dupe vote when the questioner doesn't intend to let it pass.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: "Help at all costs" is where Experts Exchange, Yahoo Answers, forums go wrong. Stack Exchange was founded explicitly to be different. We have a quality control system. I'm saying that bypassing it due to laziness it is not cool. For all you know, with your undownvotable, unreviewable, uneditable comment, maybe your half-answer is wrong? Maybe it's dangerous! You just anti-helped! "I just want to help" is really not a good enough reason to bypass the entire SE model, IMO. If you want to do that go to Quora or Yahoo Answers!

Comment: @Barry, to me being lazy would be *walking away without helping*, not *posting a comment*. It looks like you're advocating the former. And the *entire SE model* has comments, maybe you should just deal with them being here.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yes, if you don't have a proper answer to post, then don't post it. Doing a half-job in the wrong place, which is being lazy, is _worse_ than doing nothing. Ideally you'd write a full answer. But if you haven't the time for that, then fine! Leave it for someone else, who can help properly and reliably and in detail. There's no shame in that.

Comment: @Barry, I disagree, mostly because my leaving a comment does not interfere at all with *leaving the question to someone else*. (And I don't think my comments are half-jobs, but I'm biased). See also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210663/164403).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Leaving a comment interferes with lots of things, as I've already explained above and below. I consider it a net negative. Okay, maybe you helped the OP, maybe you didn't. But even if you did SE is about more than one OP. Also, if you think your comments are not half-jobs, then presumably you mean you think they are complete answers, so why are they not in the answer section? Now, don't get me wrong, I'm well aware I'm in the minority here .... but I still cannot comprehend the opposing argument. It's like saying blue is red. AFAICT, what I'm saying is just basic logic!! ^_^

Comment: @Barry, [`goto comment 2`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320364/answers-in-comments-revisited#comment329716_320364).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I already addressed that comment. I quoted it and explicitly debunked it with logic.

Comment: @Barry, I don't think you did. You only said *[you didn't] see how that's a valid reason.* Anyway, we'll have to agree to disagree here I'm afraid.

Comment: I like how we're all trying to answer this question in the comments section.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja: Meta is a bit different (notice the [tag:discussion] tag; Meta already breaks the Q&A model), though at this point many of the longer points made above would indeed be best suited as answers (so that they can be downvoted as appropriate!).

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet ""maybe not sure if it fully answers the question," Then why are they writing it down at all? Be sure." - except it **is** true, they're just not sure if it **fully answers the question**. "Not sure if it fully answers the question" != "Not sure if it's true". And anyway, if you're 80%, 90% or 99% sure something is true and useful, then you should still post it.

Comment: " So many questinos posters, repWhores etc. don't bother to look for dups, so why should I?" <- the essence of what's wrong with ***everything*** @MartinJames.

Comment: I'm not certain I see the harm done by just leaving a pile of bricks for someone else to build a wall with? If a comment leads to OP finding a solution, feel free to create an answer from it and reap the rep, or just ask OP to self answer it. I can see how "unanswered"-clutter might be a thing, but I don't know how big a thing it actually is. I can also see a problem with people NOT posting a half-answer in the comments which could lead to the question never getting answered at all, surely this is "worse"?

Comment: Comments are no ~extended discussion~ answers. This has been moved to ~chat~ Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=the+answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything ;-)

Comment: [**Happens with RegEx question a lot.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066175/regex-find-and-replace-pattern-matches-with-other-pattern#comment-copy)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426311) is a perfect example where I feel answering in comments is justified. Sometimes we just get useful questions that don't fit to SO's format and I hold helping people over obeying rules made for different situations.

Comment: I will often answer in comments if I am not 100% certain about whether my answer is correct. As in, it could be a complete answer, however I am not certain enough that it is to actually make it an official answer. If the asker replies that it worked, I'll make it an official answer.

Comment: sometimes I'd like to help without increasing the amount of my given answers, primarily because I'm not looking for _easy_ reputation. Furthermore I might want to keep high my `accepted answer / answer` ratio and I've good reason to think that user will not be able to pick an answer. If there was a way to post an answer not up/downvotable that not increases the number of personal answers, I would always answer.

Comment: I get that this might not be an exact duplicate since it's *hinting at* a feature request to do something about this issue, but unless that request is made explicit, it seems like it's the same conversation otherwise.

Comment: @sphanley: That was two years ago. This is about what we should do given that the problem is _still going on_ (and getting worse).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara "I find most answers posted as comments are stab-in-the-dark answers" <-- I don't think that's remotely true. I see a huge amount of answers-as-comments that very clearly correct (e.g. the answer-as-comment in OP).

Comment: @Barry: The point is that there is no way to distinguish between the two, because comments cannot be edited/downvoted/reviewed. You and I may be able to distinguish between them, because we are C++ experts, but a less experienced user has no idea. That makes this, in general, _an explicitly harmful activity_. And it's 100% contrary to the entire purpose of being here. I remain astounded at the extent to which people will go to defend doing the polar opposite of what SE is designed for us to do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I meant more correct as in the *writer* of the comment knew with certainty that they were correct (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408590/invalid-use-of-non-static-member-where-member-is-const-and-list-initialised#comment60433215_36408590) for wall o' shaming purposes - that comment is longer than the main part of my answer!)

Comment: @Barry: Okay but the whole point is that as certain as we think we are, we are subject to voting because nobody can ever be sure! We are teaching, and we have peer review to ensure that we _think_ it right, actually does turn out to be right. The answer section was designed with this in mind. The comment section was not. Yet for some reason everybody seems intent on using the comment section. I just don't get it.

Comment: @Light I'm not at all disagreeing with you.

Comment: @Barry: Good stuff :)

Comment: http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/a/2299/14359

Answer (score 50):

Well, I'm watching this discussion a while now.

To drop my 2 cents in:

I often write an *"answering comment"* while I'm voting to close a question for

- trivial bug, misconception or typo
- unclear questions (where I'm not sure if that would be a valid answer)
- *too broad* questions, or questions asking for 3rd party resources, when I know I'd still leave a useful link maybe

> Answers as comments cannot be downvoted, reviewed, edited or bountied. They do not contribute to the metric of "how many answers has this question?" which feeds into a few automated processes, various "can be marked as duplicate?" rules and so forth. These are all problems.

These may be problems concerning answers, comments are different and that might be exactly the point why they've been left as comments and not as answers.

My main point still is, I (usually) don't write answers for clearly off-topic questions, since this will just encourage asking more off-topic questions.

Comment: Sometimes I leave a comment "try *x* - if it works, I'll know what the mistake was and I will explain it". Which isn't as random as it sounds; usually when there is too little - and sometimes way too much - 'context' in the question.

Comment: Do you not think that answering off-topic questions only encourages people to _keep asking them_? And that answering them in the wrong place only adds to your wrongness?

Comment: @RadLexus Sounds like you're asking for clarifying information, which is well within the scope of a comment.

Comment: The first one - typo or misconception - is my usual reason, and yes, I am also voting to close the question.
I can't honestly imagine how that could encourage people to ask more about typos. SO is all about helping people. We can help people even if the question gets closed & deleted afterwards.

Comment: Those aren't "problems" with answers, those are the features of answers. They're the problems with comments.

Answer (score 35):

While I don't feel as strongly about this as Lightness does, I'm seeing a *lot* of arguments being made against this which don't actually make any sense, so I feel the need to point that out in the hopes of moving the conversation somewhere a bit more productive than it's currently at.

---

> Only bad answers fit in comments anyway.

As a universal assertion, I strongly disagree. There are plenty of questions for which the best possible answer takes only 3-5 sentences, assuming we place at least some value on being concise and to the point rather than rambling on about tangential information solely to reach some arbitrary minimum answer length. It's not at all uncommon for an SO question's most-upvoted answer to be very concise, while the second most-upvoted answer is the one that goes into extreme detail.

While it is *usually* the case that longer answers are better, and *usually* the best possible answer to a good question won't fit in a comment, that's definitely not always the case.

> a possible reason for posting a comment is that the answer is common and simple enough that the commenter would end up posting it several times a day if they didn't use comments

Why is this a reason to post it several times a day as a comment instead of several times a day as an answer?

If the question is "not worthy" of an answer because it's an exact duplicate, then surely the best response is to post a comment linking to the dupe target (and voting to close as dupe), rather than posting a comment summarizing the dupe target's answer, right? That would get the OP to look at a fully-fleshed out answer rather than a quick summary thereof, so it's even more helpful.

> Why bother with an answer if it's just going to be a dup? So many questinos posters, repWhores etc. don't bother to look for dups, so why should I? So, it it's short, may as well dump the dup answer to the dup question in the comments. Why make any more effort than that on a bad question?

Again, there's no explanation of why this is a reason to post a comment instead of an answer. I think the implied premise here is that answers take more effort, but a 3-5 sentence answer doesn't take any more effort than a 3-5 sentence comment.

> Where exactly would you draw the line in the rules between when to post a comment or an answer?

"Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid answering questions in comments."

^ That is the placeholder text we see every time we click "add comment" under a question. The distinction seems perfectly straightforward to me.

> Also if someone just knows half of the answer for sure and posts it as comment, should it be a comment or answer then?

I thought there was already a consensus that you should post it *as an answer* if it's a useful half-answer, and don't post anything at all if it's not useful.

One MSE thread on the subject: [What do I do if I know only half the answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/what-do-i-do-if-i-know-only-half-the-answer-to-a-question)

> leaving a comment does not interfere at all with leaving the question to someone else

Again, this isn't unique to comments. Someone can always post a better answer later.

---

Now these are the questions I think are not clearly settled and thus we *should* be talking about:

1. Is it a net gain or a net loss when someone posts an answer as a comment rather than posting nothing at all? What if that answer is incorrect and downvote-worthy?
2. What should we do if someone posts an answer as a comment? Custom flag? Post an answer ourselves with the same information? Do nothing at all?

---

Here's my personal reasoning on the matter.

- For the OP, a comment answer and a real answer with the same content are equally helpful. I don't see any reason the OP would care one way or the other.
- For the poster, a comment answer and a real answer with the same content are equally easy to post. In fact, the real answer is probably easier to post because it has a better editor.
- A comment answer cannot be voted on or edited, and it does not appear in review queues. In other words, an answer posted as a comment gets far less oversight and feedback compared to a real answer. This is definitely a bad thing if the comment answer is incorrect or otherwise downvote-worthy. If the comment answer is entirely correct, it's not clear if this matters.
- A comment answer may get auto-hidden after too many other comments are posted, but a real answer will never be auto-hidden. If we assume that answer voting reflects the quality of the information better than comment voting does (which seems likely to me), then this is a reason to prefer posting answers as real answers.
- Real answers affect reputation, while comment answers do not. If we again assume answer voting reflects the quality of the information, then it seems like a good thing that your reputation is affected by the quality of what you post. And you always have the option of posting a community wiki answer if you don't want the rep for some reason.

So...I can't actually think of a single reason why it would be better for the OP or for the answerer to post an answer as a comment instead of a real answer, assuming the answerer is acting in good faith. If the answerer is trying to avoid downvotes for a lazy answer, then there's a clear advantage to posting in comments, but hopefully we can all agree that no one should be doing that.

I'm not active enough on SO to judge the severity of this problem, but I can't escape the conclusion that it is a bad thing, since **no one has mentioned a single legitimate reason for posting answers as comments** thus far, and the number of clearly illegitimate reasons presented as if they were logically sound is a little bit worrying.

What if anything we should do about it probably depends on how severe the problem is. Since I have no opinion on its severity on StackOverflow, I'm abstaining from that aspect of the question for the time being. I know that on Programmers.SE (where I'm most active) this is an extremely minor issue, which is why I'm simply ignoring it in favor of more serious problems.

P.S. I do think it's possible to legitimately argue in favor of comment answers, but at the moment every argument I can think of involves a highly controversial premise. For instance, if you think it's a good thing to answer off-topic questions solely to be helpful to the OP, there's a reasonable argument that posting such an answer as a comment is better, but I think many of us would prefer that such questions simply don't get answered at all.

Comment: Nice one. Very eloquent :) And hopefully you know me well enough not to assume I'm only saying that because you're leaning in my direction :p

Comment: re PS yeah exactly - that's the only truly debatable scenario I've ever had presented to me thus far, and I think even then we can probably agree that answering offtopic questions only rewards them and encourages more of them. Can't see how posting them in the wrong place changes that.

Comment: (Still reading your answer, sorry, but concerning *Why is this a reason to post it several times a day as a comment instead of several times a day as an answer?*). It doesn't distribute that way. I never leave the same comment more than once a *month* I believe. It's the *number of users doing this* that gives that impression.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Fair enough; I was quoting that from one of the comments above so I had no idea if anyone actually did that.

Comment: @Ixrec, okay, I think I pretty much got your point (and I won't vote your answer either way, because I still have to think about this), but [I crave more data](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Mentat) and I'm wondering how you intend to *convince* about then *enforce* this. Convincing can arguably be done on Meta, but enforcing would require filtering all comments on costly and disputable criteria. How would you suggest we handle this? *(In other words -- what would happen to me if I do not stop doing what I'm doing now?)*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi At the moment I'm not convinced that "enforcement" of any form is required; again I don't know how serious the problem is on SO. I guess the ideal would simply be getting a community consensus on whether it's a bad thing and what actions (custom flag? respond with comment encouraging commenter to post as answer?) would be acceptable when we stumble across a comment answer.

Comment: RE your PS about trying to be helpful in off-topic questions. I would like to do this, but don't want to add an answer as any upvoted/accepted answers would cause the question to avoid the Roomba. I want the question gone but don't want to dismiss the person asking the question.

Comment: So @DavidG you literally answer in the wrong place in order to circumvent the system? To answer doomed questions? It would be better to start a thread on meta about changing the Roomba system if you don't think it works properly.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Not always, but I do think that some users deserve a little help. I'm not trying to circumvent anything, what exactly is the issue with doing this? I will vote-to-close, down-vote and throw delete-votes as appropriate too. Having said that, I have no issue with suggesting changes to Roomba, perhaps it could ignore CW answers?

Comment: @DavidG: You're not trying to circumvent anything but you post answers as not-answers because you know that the system classifies questions differently based on whether they have answers and you don't want it to classify the questions you answer on the grounds for which it was designed? Sorry, looks like a textbook case of circumvention to me!

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet So you would prefer me not to answer at all and not give the user anything? Just curious, that's a reasonable opinion but not one that I necessarily share in *all* situations.

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, of course. Either the question should be answered or it should not.

Comment: Sometimes answers on poor questions can get down-voted because they answer a poor question, so it can also be seen as a measure to try helping the poster without the risk of someone using their free will to vote up/down on a on answer as they desire. I'm not saying that's a good thing, but it does happen.

Comment: Just another consequence of the rules the roomba uses to delete questions... If the question has a positively scored answer, it won't be deleted to preserve "quality" content. Answers to poor questions often get upvoted very quickly and several times, simply because they're "correct" in that they correctly pointed out the typo, or suggested a good 3rd party tool. If they're negatively scored, the question will be automagically deleted later.

Comment: "While it is usually the case that longer answers are better,"; I've come to believe this is usually *untrue*. *Usually*, I see the rambling on from low-rep users who think if they attempt to cram all of OOP concepts down OP's throat when they could've been helped under the comment limit they are doing great work. There are some excellent and very long answers around but I don't think the average problem on SO requires great length to tackle.

Answer (score 22):

When I vote to close a question as a typo, I generally want the question to be deleted.  The close reason itself says "this [question] was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers".  But answers prevent the [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) from automatically deleting such questions after they're closed, so I point out the typo in a comment instead of an answer.

Occasionally I "answer" in a comment saying something like "What's wrong with just doing X?  Please edit your question to explain your requirements."; an actual request for clarification that happens to contain an embedded answer.  I post these as comments because while they may contain an answer, it's unlikely to be the answer the asker was looking for.  Posting it as an answer would prevent the asker from fixing their question (because it would invalidate my answer).

Comment: Do you not think there's a _reason_ that answers prevent deletion? And that by posting your answer as a comment instead, all you're doing is circumventing network policy? _"I post these as comments because while they may contain an answer, it's unlikely to be the answer the asker was looking for."_ This, also, seems like the polar opposite of what we should be doing.

Comment: No, by posting it as a comment he's preventing the question from getting into a state where this absolutely useless question will live on for  years, while also helping a fellow developer with an honest mistake (in the case of typos/syntax errors.) It's a win-win situation in a case like this. Should the question have not been asked in the first place? Sure, but there's nothing we can do about that now other than downvote/close it. Answering it with an answer is harmful.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not the one in the screenshot you posted but I admit **I'm guilty**, sometimes I do it. Let me explain:

- Sometimes question is really too trivial, RTFM style. Yes you may write a proper answer but it wouldn't add anything to what you already can find (hidden) in documentation. Often it's just a quick hint for a question I also voted to close (for an user I think it's **not help-vampire**).
- Sometimes it's a quick & dirty solution or just one line of code. To my understanding **an answer should be complete**. Yes, it should solve the problem but it should also explain why it didn't work as OP expected. Illustrate corner cases and so on. This can't fit in a comment.
- Sometimes you just don't have time (or a keyboard...) to write a full half-decent answer.

---

What's the problem with that? Is it better to post a *bad* answer instead of a *good* comment? Very often someone else (mostly new users) will then write an answer from such comments. When they add enough value (and especially if they credit original comment's author) I will also happily upvote them. Not everything is about 30 rep points...

---

Of course this is my personal point of view, honestly I didn't even think SO may have a policy about this behavior (I admit it may be a misuse of comments). Ready to change my mind (and behavior) if SO guidelines (and its users feelings) are different...

Comment: _"Is it better to post a bad answer instead of a good comment?"_ A good comment requests clarification or critiques. Nothing else. If you don't have time (or a keyboard...) to write a full half-decent answer, then simply don't. If you give "quick hints" to questions that should be closed, you only reward the asker and encourage them to ask more off-topic questions in the future.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I agree it's a misuse of comments, I still see it as better than a succinct answer. Obviously I'll keep an eye on this thread, I honestly never thought it may be an annoying behavior and I'll adhere to SO policy about this.

Comment: I join `Sometimes question is really too trivial, RTFM style` reason. After I post trivial answer in a comment, I always hope that person who asked question will post a self-answer. Some people do, some don't (some new users don't return anymore)

Comment: @ASh I agree. It's not everything about gaining 30 rep points. Someone (rarely, I have to say) explicitly ask to post it as answer and in that case I suggest them to do it.

Comment: If a question is too trivial and RTFM, _you should not encourage the OP by providing the solution_. You should close the question, and let the OP learn how to, well, RTFM!!

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, too trivial for one person doesn't mean it is trivial for another. When I see from question that person really { tried / tried a lot } to help himself before asking on SO, I see nothing wrong in constructive comments, suggesting a solution for their issue

Comment: @Ash: It's about whether the question is too trivial for this site. We have quality standards. Y'all are brazenly stamping all over them and being proud of it.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I strongly agree we should (try to) keep average quality higher but let's face the reality: 95% of new questions are trivial or even bad. Some of them deserve to be deleted immediately. Some others may be solved with a comment (and eventually then closed/deleted) but user honestly tried to do his _homework_. Others are in a _gray area_. I'd post few examples but I don't want meta effect on that

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Have you ever stopped to wonder _why_ 95% of new questions are trivial or even bad? Yes, it's because everybody knows they can get their trivial or even bad questions answered here, in the comment section, even when their question will be closed or deleted shortly thereafter (which the OP doesn't care about).

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I can't say you're wrong about this but I admit I'm not sure about _where_ quality threshold should be set. About answers as comments I think points 2 and (arguably) 3 still apply. I'm curious to see where this post will lead, I didn't ever deeply think about this issue.

Comment: If I'm about to write or in the process of writing an in-depth answer, and I notice somebody else posts a comment with the salient substance of my answer, then I abandon my answer. I post answers to help people, not to get rep, and it feels dirty for me to re-post somebody else's comment as an answer. This is anecdotal, but it suggests that answer-comments can have a chilling effect, discouraging actual answers.

Comment: @Thriggle that's also true but if an answer really adds value to a comment then it's welcome even if it partially repeat a comment (just few days ago I had exactly this issue but I still posted my answer because comment was really too concise). It's not always in one way, I think

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet *If you don't have time (or a keyboard...) to write a full half-decent answer, then simply don't* Isn't SO all about helping the OP and the community? If my comment could help the OP (or someone else in writing a good answer), why refrain from commenting?

Comment: @gldraphael: Because we're not about "helping at all costs" (otherwise literally everything would be on-topic). The site's very existence is all about quality standards. This behaviour results in a huge quantity of material posted in the wrong place, breaking all the models that have been implemented to help maintain those quality standards. The end result is decay of the system and eventually collapse of the community.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet correct me if I'm wrong - but I think the site's existence is about helping each other. The quality of questions/answers needs to be maintained so that the site is helpful. A low quality answer, or an incomplete answer is not going to do the site any good in my opinion. And repeating what I said - If my comment could help the OP (or someone else in writing a good answer), why refrain from commenting?

Comment: @gldraphael I partially agree with Barry. I agree we should try to keep quality as high as possible, bad questions or questions from help vampires should not be answered (it doesn't matter if in comments or in the proper place). However I agree with you about the _site mission_, if we can help then better something than nothing. Someone else may (as it usually happens) will then write a proper answer. However I'm still waiting to see a general consensus (guideline?) about this from SO employees or at least from moderators.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti If your long, detailed answer really doesn't add any value beyond that contained in a short comment, why write it? I'd imagine your detailed answer adds context, example usage, design concepts or similar to help the OP (and future visitors). A comment with a code snippet doesn't detract from that.

Comment: But it _does_ have all of the downsides that I've described several times, that nobody seems to be listening to.

Comment: @Basic but a comment is not visible (especially in long discussions) and it may be deleted in any moment by a mod "cleaning the room". Note that I agree to do it (someone else will post an answer, almost for sure) but I also understand Barry & Co. feelings (it's a misuse and comments - even if wrong - can't be downvoted, edited and improved).

Comment: @Basic Because the comment doesn't add value. It's not that an answer adds value "beyond that contained in a short comment"... it's that it adds value *period*.

Comment: A proper answer has more value than a comment. Not writing an answer because there's already a comment with a snippet is a mistake. I don't for a moment believe a long detailed answer has no value (sorry, I thought I was pretty clear about that).

Answer (score 5):

I am just trying to give my 2cents as a recently active user and trying to find my way inbetween the lines of what is acceptable and what is not.

I let some answers that I can give go by because I don't feel proficient enough in these cases to give a proper explanation with the code I supply. Then there are those questions that can be answered with a function(s) name or very simple things, that might not even be proper questions to begin with.

I am guilty in these cases to sometimes leave that simple answer in the comments, but again knowing the code to a solution and being able to properly explain the reasoning behind it are two different things. That's why maybe not only I but more users leave the answer(s) in a comment instead of writing it as an answer.

Don't get me wrong, I completely agree with the OP. I am just trying to give insight in what could give me as a new/unexperienced/passionate/driven user any reason to post it in a comment instead of an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the tastefully-named BarryTheHatchet (er, well now back to Lightness): answers belong as answers. Answers don't belong in the question and answers don't belong in comments. Full stop. Following the discussion on here, really all of the arguments in favor of posting comments in answers really seem to boil down to:

> This question is clearly beneath me to write a full answer to. Instead, I will post the solution as a comment.

I don't see any of the arguments that are really substantively dissimilar to that thought process. And comments aren't answers - they're not reviewable, votable, editable. If they're wrong or incomplete, at best you can just write another comment. Countless times I've seen wrong comment-answers at +5, but the correcting comment only at +1 and disappear into the fold - that can be wildly misleading.

It's also quite annoying from the perspective of asking a question and then receiving comment-answers instead. What do I do at that point? Just aggregate the comments myself and self-answer? That's really not how the process is supposed to work.

There is one exception that I consider valid. Fairly regularly, I close questions as dupes of canonical questions that have wonderfully thorough answers (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/2069064) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/2069064)), but it might be difficult for newer users to understand just *how* their question is a dupe - so I will close it but then write the utra specific comment (e.g. "you need `typename X::type`"). I don't want to have to write answers like:

> You can't just write `X::type`, you need to write `typename X::type`. See [this question that is clearly a dupe] for a thorough explanation of why that is the case.

since that defeats the purpose of having a duplicate close reason to begin with.

---

That said, how do we fix this? We already have a solution for answers in the question (just edit them out), but there's nothing to be done for answers in the comments (unless the user kindly provides us with an orthogonal flag reason, like "you're missing `typename` before `X::type`, you Nazi"). I think there should be a flag for that though. Simply:

> I am flagging this comment as an answer

Make Answers Answers Again!

Comment: It's fascinating that an answer like this gets downvotes :( It's based on logic. It makes sense. It gives proper, rational arguments. Sigh!

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet At least as an answer, it can get downvotes, justifiable or otherwise. Boom, mic drop.

Comment: I too [have flagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323627/download-sharepoint-list-attachment-in-ie-browser#comment60299279_36323627) as duplicates, then in comments explained how the linked answers relate to the questions. (Partially because I've asked questions myself and received dupe links that didn't directly relate to my question.) However, I don't think that's the type of behavior that @BarryTheHatchet is concerned about here.

Comment: @Thriggle Not saying that's what OP is concerned about. Just saying that I believe the rule should be "answers should never go in comments", with one singular exception.

Comment: So [is this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399534/objects-error-using-vbs#comment60422551_36399534) an answer or a question in the comments in your opinion? The OP didn't post enough code to determine if it was a typo or not.  The *question* I asked basically was to determine which of 2 obvious errors were in the code. Should I not put any context at all in a question and just comment "post the full code"? The question deserves to be closed as a typo and eventually deleted (full stop), but now it has a Roomba shield sitting on it. Do I downvote a "correct" answer instead?

Comment: @Comintern If the question doesn't have enough code, leave a comment to make the question an MCVE and vote to close.

Comment: One other scenario you haven't covered: I don't care about the rep, I don't have the time/motivation to write a detailed, referenced answer but I want to help the OP.

Comment: @Basic That just falls into the "this question is beneath me" umbrella - if it's not worth your time to write an answer, then just don't write an answer. It's that simple. There's nothing wrong with not answering a question. And if you're already spending your time writing a comment, then you could've spent that time writing an answer too.

Answer (score -7):

I agree with you, sometimes the direct answer pops out in a comment, but there's nothing to be done about it except to write up the answer and flesh it out. (When I comment "Answers go in the answers" the response is usually agreement, but they didn't have the time to risk putting out content that's off the mark.)

Usually, I find that answers in the comments are less than ideal, and good answers will have deeper insight and caveats.

If you think a good answer can be given in a single comment, your standards are possibly too low. My personal strategy is to write canonical answers - but I don't think short answers are good. I try to educate my audience and give a deeper understanding of underlying principles and put the subject under discussion in some context. That usually takes more than can fit in a comment.

So if the comments make it easy, as an eager answerer, the least you can do is explain the why and how, or give some context.

> preventing people writing any answers in the comment section?

How does that create value? If anything, it destroys value when people who want to (and can) contribute but not with the larger stakes of the answer go away. Not sure how you're going to implement it, either. What's a regular expression for an answer look like? Tell moderators to convert comments into answers? And when half-baked comments get downvoted to heck, what then?

I don't think it makes sense to expect any changes, **other than to just to educate contributors that "Answers go in the Answers."**

But I think they already know it.

---

## A clear statement of policy

It occurs to me that what we need is a clear statement of policy - I propose:

> Redundant answers in the comments should be flagged for removal by mods. Otherwise, write it up as a real Answer (if it's bad, say why), then flag it for removal.

Comment: You explain why longer answers are better than shorter answers (which I don't believe is always the case, but that's another topic). This question is about coming to a consensus on preventing people writing _any_ answers in the comment section. The quality of the answer given is not relevant, except to say that if it were posted in the proper place, you'd at least be able to denote your opinion on its quality, by downvoting it.

Comment: Yes, education is precisely what I'm after. And perhaps a flag reason if things really get out of control. (Or, at least, an understanding that a suitable custom flag reason would be approved.)

Comment: _"(When I comment "Answers go in the answers" the response is usually agreement, but they didn't have the time to risk putting out content that's off the mark.)"_ Yet, ironically, that's then precisely what they've done. And they've done so in a medium that cannot be reviewed, edited, downvoted. Isn't that _much worse_? They'd have been better off just leaving it all alone altogether, leaving it for someone with time who's sure of what they're writing. You don't _always_ have to write something down in response to a question!

Answer (score -10):

Education will accomplish nothing. "Official" policy will accomplish nothing.

I've encountered a particular user in the Lua tag who abjectly refuses to actually post answers most of the time, even when confronted about it. The closest thing to a justification for this behavior is the general idea that he doesn't have the time to make his comment answer-worthy. That is, he'll post a quick one-off line of code or a couple of sentences as a comment that solves the problem. But a "proper" answer would require more text, even just to get past 30 characters, let alone achieve the status of being "good" by some measurement. So he doesn't bother.

And the actions of this one user has rendered the unanswered question list in the Lua tag completely worthless for finding questions to answer.

Such users cannot be appealed to or reasoned with. They cannot be educated because *they do not care.* They have their own beliefs about how SO works, and they're following them. We cannot *make* them abide by standards that they don't believe in, and they cannot be convinced otherwise.

The only possible solution is to add the ability to force someone's comment to become that person's answer. Otherwise, such malicious users will remain malicious.

Comment: How can you say that official policy accomplishes nothing? Official policy _made_ this site. Official policy guides what we do, and what moderators ensure we continue doing. Policy is literally the backbone of the entire network. If there's some guy who refuses to follow the rules, then that guy should be blocked from writing posts. I've suggested adding a flag for this in the past. It seems like, except for the "it won't happen" element, we basically agree?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: "*Official policy made this site.*" No, people *agreeing* with that policy "made this site". It is official policy that we don't allow crap questions, yet they're always being posted. Official policy only matters when people agree to it.

Comment: And I'm asking to form official policy and for people to agree to it.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: Official policy already exists on the matter: questions should not be answered in comments. People still violate that policy for the same reason they violate the policy on crap questions or any other frequently violated policy.

Comment: @Ni​​​​​​​​​​​​col: I have not seen that policy enforced in any meaningful way, nor anyone agreeing with it. I'm asking for us to investigate doing those two things. Is that okay?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: "*I have not seen that policy enforced in any meaningful way*" Being "official policy" has nothing to do with enforcement.

Comment: @Ni​​​​​​​​​​​​col: What would you enforce, if not official policy? o.O

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet community consensus of course.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: The point of my answer is that ***all it takes is one person***. One single person completely ruined the Lua tag's unanswered question list. It doesn't matter how much consensus you have or what policy you create. All it takes is the actions of a single individual to make the site measurably worse in this regard.

Comment: @NicolBolas: They didn't "ruin" it. The unanswered question list contains a list of unanswered questions. If you provide an answer, the question is no longer unanswered. I simply cannot understand your viewpoint here. You are pushing for the polar opposite of how things are designed to work.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: The point of looking through the unanswered question list is to find interesting questions that are worth answering. A question which *has an answer* is not worth answering, even if that answer is a comment. I am not sifting through the unanswered question list so that I can copy&paste stuff that someone else already said.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I think you are missing the point. the point is these "unanswered questions" ARE answered, in the comments.

Comment: @KevinB: Then post them as answers so that they no longer show up in the unanswered question section....

Comment: I'm forgetting which comments go on which answer. We may be talking at cross-purposes on this one. So are we saying here that because _one_ person does it wrong, we might as well _all_ do it wrong?

Comment: No, not at all. the point is you can't enforce it. You can try to educate, but it's going to fall on deaf ears.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: Actually, it's not merely that you can't enforce it. It's that all it takes is one person who chooses not to follow the rules to screw it all up.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: "*Then post them as answers so that they no longer show up in the unanswered question section....*" I do not come to Stack Overflow to be a janitor.

Comment: I think that if someone is ignoring official policy and community consensus to such an extreme degree that they should be warned. If they continue to do so, posting privileges should be entirely revoked. If you refuse to play by the rules, then you don't get to play. You do more harm than good by not following the rules.